# PCRE Nginx regexp matching any of words or ending with suffix

Tags: regex, nginx, pcre, nginx-location

How can I write an Nginx regexp mathing location containg foo|bar|baz or ending with /beautifu.html?

sth like `location ~ ^/.*(foo|bar|baz)/.*$` but also matching .*/beautiful.html

Comment: The `|` operator is used to separate alternative regular expressions. The `^/.*` and the `.*$` is unnecessary. You could try: `location ~ (foo|bar|baz)/|/beautiful.html$ { ... }`

Answer (score -1):

Just add `/beautifu.html` before the dollar sign to make sure the URL ends with /beautifu.html

Comment: (Re)read the question:“location contains `foo|bar|baz` **or** ends with `/beautiful.html`”